# Limit the shipping state to one preselected value in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, hook-woocommerce

I need to limit the woocommerce shipping state to one (one state in India), without changing the state in billing address. I have tried using woocommerce_states hook, but this will replace state in both shipping and billing address.

I have been searching for the solution for the past one week, but not able to find the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

**Code updated:**

First you need to make some settings for your shop (where the selected shop state will be the shipping state) and the only available shipping country will be india:

[image]

The following code will set the shop location state as the unique available shipping state and will make the dropdown readonly (inactive) in Checkout and My account > Edit address pages:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'shipping_state_preselected_read_only', 900, 1 );
function shipping_state_preselected_read_only($fields) {
    // Get shop location country and state
    $shop_country_code = WC()->countries->get_base_country();
    $shop_state_code   = WC()->countries->get_base_state();
    $shop_state_name   = WC()->countries->get_allowed_country_states()[$shop_country_code][$shop_state_code];

    // Set customer shipping country and state to shop location
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country($shop_country_code);
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_state($shop_state_code);

    // Set shipping country field to shop location
    $fields['shipping_state']['option']  = array( $shop_state_code => $shop_state_name );
    $fields['shipping_state']['default'] = $shop_state_code;
    $fields['shipping_state']['value']   = $shop_state_code;

    // Make the field read only
    $fields['shipping_state']['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled' => 'disabled');

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Only one shipping state readonly in checkout and my account edit address (the shop based state):

[image]

> There will not be any validation problem with the country as India is preselected as the unique shipping country.

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion, but the problem is that it's throwing the validation error " Shipping State / County is a required field ". Do you have any idea? Thanks in Advance

Comment: @DeepeshKumarR I have made an update with some settings screen shots… This is pure php without jQuery. tested and works without any validation problem. Please have a try.

Comment: thanks..this is exactly what I was looking for! much appreciated

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Still throwing validation error Shipping State / County is a required field.

Answer (score 1):

first set the shipping location in woo commerce shipping setting page. I have set "India"

Review below screen.
[image]

Then paste the below code your active theme functions.php file.
I have set shipping only state only "Tamilnadu".

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_shipping_states');
function checkout_shipping_states() {
  if(!is_checkout()) {
    return;
  }
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(document.body).on('country_to_state_changed', function(event, args) {
    function set_shipping_states(states) {
     var $shipping_state = $('#shipping_state');
     $shipping_state.find('option:not([value=""])').remove();

     for(state in states) {
      $shipping_state.append('<option id="' + state + ' value="' + state + '">' + states[state] + '</option>');
     }
    }

    var $shipping_country = $('#shipping_country');

    var new_shipping_states = {};
    switch($shipping_country.val()) {
     case 'IN':
      new_shipping_states = {
       'TN': 'Tamil Nadu'
      }
      break;
    }

    if(!$.isEmptyObject(new_shipping_states)) {
     set_shipping_states(new_shipping_states);
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
 <?php
};
```

Review below screen

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks a ton! This worked, hope it will not affect further process. Are you able to find any hooks for the same? I tried searching, but couldn't be able to figure out. Will this javascript change makes any issue? Thanks in Advance

Comment: This concept currently working our demo site without issue.

Comment: Latest woocommerce code break the jQuery. Can you please check now?